# Livemedia-creator exits with "NoneType" error after successful installation

Tags: docker, jenkins, nonetype

We are running livemedia-creator inside a fedora docker with Jenkins as a build environment.
After the anaconda installer inside the livemedia-creator exited without an error, the livemedia-creator throws the generic error seen below. 
The error appeared randomly and persists when we go back to earlier revisions of our software and build environment (e.g. Docker image).

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Edit: 
What we tried so far: We built on two different Fedora docker images (28, 29) with two different libvirt versions(4.1, 4.7) and two different livemedia-creator versions (28.26, 29.26)

Jenkins log:

```
livemedia-creator --make-disk --image-name=tmcs-server-raw.img --ks=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ISIS-XM-G5-Env-OS/TMCS-Server-Base/tmcs-server/ks_lmc.cfg --iso=tmcs-server.iso --resultdir=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ISIS-XM-G5-Env-OS/TMCS-Server-Base/lmc_result --vnc=vnc=:0

2019-02-20 09:16:44,887: livemedia-creator v28.26-1

2019-02-20 09:16:44,887: selinux is Disabled

2019-02-20 09:16:45,044: disk_img = /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ISIS-XM-G5-Env-OS/TMCS-Server-Base/lmc_result/tmcs-server-raw.img

2019-02-20 09:16:45,044: Using disk size of 8194MiB

2019-02-20 09:16:45,045: install_log = /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ISIS-XM-G5-Env-OS/TMCS-Server-Base/virt-install.log

2019-02-20 09:16:45,294: qemu vnc=:0

2019-02-20 09:16:45,295: Running qemu

2019-02-20 09:16:45,943: Processing logs from ('127.0.0.1', 38578)

2019-02-20 09:28:23,317: Installation finished without errors.

2019-02-20 09:28:23,317: Shutting down log processing

2019-02-20 09:28:23,318: unmounting the iso

2019-02-20 09:28:23,384: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Software Versions:
Fedora 28, Jenkins 2.164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution after some trial and error.
Solution: We installed an older version for livemedia-creator (lorax-28.10-1.fc28 running on Fedora 28).

It seems to be a known bug with the latest lorax Version:
https://github.com/weldr/lorax/issues/614